# How to escape characters and in the same time put variables in a Json - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services

Im using nodejs for AWS SES, but my problem is with a json, i cant make it work with variables and in the same time scaping chars:

My code:

```
const EmailUsingTemplate1 = {
                    "Source": dataForm.email_sender,
                    "Template": "EntranceVisitInReception",
                    "Destination": {
                        "ToAddresses": [ dataForm.friend_email
                                        ]
                    },
                    "TemplateData": "{ \"condominium\":\"Las brisas\", \"visitor_name\": \"alligator\", \"user_name\": \"izzy\", \"date\": \"12 de febrero\", \"time\": \"18:00\"  }"
    }
```

Where dataForm.email_sender is a variable, and is working fine, but in the TemplateData is the problem, i cant make it work with variables, i want to replace **"Las brisas", "alligator", "izzy", "12 de febrero", "18:00"**, with variables, like **dataForm.condominium, dataForm.visitor_name, dataForm.user_name, dataForm.date and dataForm.time**, can u help me with that?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the @neurotik answer was kinda okey, but not worked, until i make this:

```
const EmailUsingTemplate1 = {
                    "Source": dataForm.email_sender,
                    "Template": "EntranceVisitInReception",
                    "Destination": {
                        "ToAddresses": [ dataForm.friend_email
                                        ]
                    },
                    "TemplateData": `{ "condominium":"${dataForm.condominium}", "visitor_name": "${dataForm.visitor_name}", "user_name": "${dataForm.user_name}", "date": "${dataForm.date}", "time": "${dataForm.time}" }`
                }
```

Small differences i know, but it worked nice. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Notice `EmailUsingTemplate1` key `TemplateData` is a string. If am understanding correctly, the desire is to update `TemplateData` values you'll need to first parse the JSON string.

```
const TemplateDataObject = JSON.parse(EmailUsingTemplate1.TemplateData);

// Update some values
TemplateDataObject.condominium = dataForm.condominium;
TemplateDataObject.visitor_name = dataForm. visitor_name;
// ...etc

// Store in same format back in the original object
EmailUsingTemplate1.TemplateData = JSON.stringify(TemplateDataObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)...

```js
const dataForm = { condominium: "Las brisas" };

const EmailUsingTemplate1 = {
  Source: dataForm.email_sender,
  Template: "EntranceVisitInReception",
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses: [ dataForm.friend_email ]
  },
  TemplateData: `{ "condominium":"${dataForm.condominium}", "visitor_name": "alligator", "user_name": "izzy", "date": "12 de febrero", "time": "18:00" }`
}

console.log(EmailUsingTemplate1);
```